# Selenium C#: Actions class works during debug mode but does not work during regular test run

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action, webdriverwait

I am using Actions class to move to an element and then to click on it.
The following code works when I execute it on debug mode, but the same fails during normal test execution. In my case, State is a dropdown and I am trying to select a state from a dropdown.

There was a similar question and I used all options mentioned over there, but still couldn't get pass it.

Code trials:

```
Driver.WaitForPageLoad();
Driver.WaitForAjax();
BrowserActions action = new BrowserActions(Driver);            
action.MoveToElement(Driver.FindElement(State().Query)).Build().Perform();
Driver.WaitUntil(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(State().Query), 120);
action.Click().Perform();
Driver.WaitForAjax();
Driver.WaitForPageLoad();
```

Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

From a generic approach, `MoveToElement()` would be successfull only when [`ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm) or atleast [`ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementIsVisible.htm) succeeds.

So you can optimize your code block as follows:

```
Driver.WaitForPageLoad();
Driver.WaitForAjax();
BrowserActions action = new BrowserActions(Driver);            
action.MoveToElement(Driver.WaitUntil(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(State().Query), 120)).Click().Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but even this is not working for me. Any other suggestions - totally different from movetoElement also is okay?